# Why am I unable to change the width of an image overflowing the parent, while I can do so with height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div in my page that has the following properties:

```
#viewport{
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 323px;
    height: 323px;
}
```

Inside this is an  element with the following properties:

```
#image{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

The image can be dragged throughout the viewport (jQuery draggable) and anytime it overflows it is hidden, the dragging works fine.  When I try to change the height and width using `$.height()` and `$.width()`, the height changes perfectly, while the width only changes if it is less than the width of the viewport, so it wont go wider than 323 pixels.  The height keeps expanding outside of the viewport fine.  They both expand at the same rate, and when I log what values I am using for the width and height, they are both correct, the width just isn't working.   Does anyone know why this might be happening only for the width?

Comment: You have your max-width for images set to 100% somewhere in your CSS?

Comment: If you're using the HTML5Boilerplate, they set the `max-width` for images to 100% (as @Gothematic mentioned).  I imagine other similar tools might do so as well, so you might not even know you're doing it.

Comment: I never knew of max-width.  I used my chrome developer tools and yep... the image has max-width: 100%.  It came from css in my jQueryUI theme.  So thanks!!!  It works now.  I would pick this as best answer if it wasn't in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your max-width for images set to 100% somewhere in your CSS?

Comment: Thank you for this answer!  I had never heard of max-width before, so I didn't notice my jQueryUI theme was leaking this into my images.  Now it works perfectly!